# Error using images.internal.imageDisplayParsePVPairs in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, warp

I am trying to run [this code](http://web.mit.edu/emeyers/www/warping/warp.html) in order to warp an image, but I can not run that properly on **Matlab R2018b** and get the following error:

```
>> captureWarpPoints('man11.jpg');
Error using images.internal.imageDisplayParsePVPairs (line 71)
The parameter, notruesize, is not recognized by imageDisplayParsePVPairs

Error in images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs (line 69)
[common_args,specific_args] = images.internal.imageDisplayParsePVPairs(varargin{:});

Error in imshow (line 245)
    images.internal.imageDisplayParseInputs({'Parent','Border','Reduce'},preparsed_varargin{:});

Error in captureWarpPoints>updateRef (line 133)
        refImgHandle = imshow(modRefImage, 'notruesize');

Error in captureWarpPoints (line 29)
updateRef(1, refImage, refPoints)
```

Note: I have **Image Processing Toolkit** installed. Here is the [source code](http://web.mit.edu/emeyers/www/warping/warp.zip).

How can I run this code properly?

Comment: Did you write captureWarpPoints? You are calling imshow somewhere with 'notruesize' as an option. That does not seem to be a valid option for calling imshow.

Comment: No, it is actually written by [someone here](http://web.mit.edu/emeyers/www/warping/warp.html) as I mentioned. Here is the [source code](http://web.mit.edu/emeyers/www/warping/warp.zip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, these lines must change in order to run the code properly:

Line 17 in the **captureWarpPoints.m** must change to:

```
iptsetpref('ImshowBorder', 'tight'); % 'iptsetpref' must be lowercase not uppercase
```

Line 36 in the **captureWarpPoints.m** must change to:

```
capImgHandle = imshow(capImage, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit');
```

Line 133 in the **captureWarpPoints.m** as you wrote must change to:

```
refImgHandle = imshow(modRefImage, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit');
```

Line 26 in the **warpImage.m** must change to:

```
displaceY = griddata(x, y, zy, xi', yi);
```

Answer (score 1):

Long ago `imshow` probably had an extra option for calling `truesize` as a string argument. It does not have that syntax anymore. Instead call, truesize separately. i.e. Replace

```
imshow(I, 'truesize');
```

with

```
imshow(I);
truesize;
```

Or you can simply remove the argument and manually adjust the size to what you need.

Comment: Seems that `truesize` does not work for me, I just used `imshow(capImage, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit')` instead and answered the question myself. [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/451762-error-using-images-internal-imagedisplayparsepvpairs-in-matlab#answer_366941) is the answer that helped me. Thanks.